How do I get rid of the weird long floating point error numbers that are shown when I convert a vector to a name of a vector
This function shows the floating point error when displaying the vector as names of another vector but not when it is displayed "normally"
test <- rep(NA, times = length(seq(from = -0.5, to =0.5 , by = 0.001)))
names(test) <- seq(from = -0.5, to =0.5 , by = 0.001)
names(test) #shows the numbers from the floating point stuff

seq(from = -0.5, to =0.5 , by = 0.001) #doesn't show them

How do I get the name to display the exact same thing that the "normal" output shows
also the explanations others have given on "similar" issues are way to complicated for me... please explain it like I'm five
I don't quite understand whether I can show somehow, that this has been answered...
but just rounding to 15 digits seems to solve my Problem :))

See R FAQ 7.31 and Why are these numbers not equal?. Also Is floating point math broken?

R, like most programming languages, often works with floating point numbers. Floating point numbers have many benefits, but one shortfall is they can't exactly capture certain numbers that are simple and clean in decimal. (As a metaphor, try cutting exactly 1/3 of a pizza by combining many small pieces, where each is only allowed to be a cut in half of another slice. It will take infinitely many cuts.) Most of the time, R can hide the fact that the numbers we're working with are often only approximations (very close ones). You are looking at one case where the hiding didn't work.

An intriguing part of your question is that in certain circumstances, R hides the floating point inaccuracies. Compare names(test) <- round(seq(from = -0.5, to = 0.5, by = 0.001), digits = 15) and names(test) <- round(seq(from = -0.5, to = 0.5, by = 0.001), digits = 16); in the first case the values are close enough to be shown in simplified form; in the 2nd case not. I presume it has to do with round nudging the values within .Machine$double.eps of the simplified form, but it's not clear to me why seq doesn't accomplish that from the start...

rounding to 15 digits seems to do it :)
Thanks so much :))

Numeric output is formatted differently than character output. names() isn't special here, you could do the same with as.character(test). A more stable way to create the list is seq(from = -500, to =500 , by = 1)/1000. That avoids many of the perils of floating point errors (but not all)
